# run command on each path in list...how to do with loop?

Tags: bash, macos, loops

We need to set a list of target folders to 777.

Please tell me there's a cleaner/smarter way to this kind of loop without having to spit out a file, to then read from the file. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

inputFile="/private/tmp/.swatchTempFolderList.txt"

echo '/Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2018/Presets/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2017/Presets/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2015.5/Presets/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2015/Presets/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC\ 2014/Presets/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CC/Presets/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2018/Presets.localized/en_US/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2017/Presets.localized/en_US/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015.3/Presets.localized/en_US/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015/Presets.localized/en_US/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2014/Presets.localized/en_US/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC/Presets.localized/en_US/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2018/Presets.localized/en_GB/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2017/Presets.localized/en_GB/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015.3/Presets.localized/en_GB/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2015/Presets.localized/en_GB/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2014/Presets.localized/en_GB/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC/Presets.localized/en_GB/Swatches/Color\ Books
/Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2018/Presets/Swatch\ Libraries
/Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2017/Presets/Swatch\ Libraries
/Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2015/Presets/Swatch\ Libraries
/Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC\ 2014/Presets/Swatch\ Libraries
/Applications/Adobe\ InDesign\ CC/Presets/Swatch\ Libraries' > "$inputFile"

while read f; do
    if [ -e "$f" ]; then
        echo "Setting 777 for $f..."
        chmod 777 "$f"
    else
        echo "Skipping, since $f does not exist..."
    fi
done < "$inputFile"

exit 0
```

Comment: What language is this Shell commands? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Don't **ever** use `chmod 777`. Marking files both executable and writable by anonymous accounts (such as those used to sandbox untrusted network code) circumvents essential system security measures. `775` is much safer (using group ownership to control which other users are allowed write access).

Comment: ...if these are all directories, and you *do* want to let even anonymous users write to them, then you'll want to also set the `+t` bit, which (when set on a directory) makes this a bit less unsafe.

Comment: Totally agree regarding danger in setting *files* to 777.

However, we are not making the files in the folder 777, only the folder itself.

Adobe and Pantone both recommended setting each of the folders in the list to 777.

This is so Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator and InDesign users who don't have admin rights can create or import swatches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump all the files into an array:

```
arr=("file1" "file2" "file3")
chmod -- 777 "${arr[@]}"
```

If you have **large** amount of files, you might encounter `Argument list too long` error. In that case, you can do this:

```
printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | xargs -0 chmod -- 777
```

or use a good old `for` loop:

```
for file in "${arr[@]}"; do
    chmod -- 777 "$file"
done
```

---

You can, of course, loop over the files directly:

```
for file in "file1" "file2" "file3"; do
    chmod -- 777 "$file"
done
```

Comment: Might use a `--` argument to ensure that the variable contents are parsed as names even if they start as dashes. And while I realize it's straight out of the question, condoning `chmod 777` by repetition without a note of warning is maybe iffy.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the feedback. Lots of good advice. I have used the `for` loop, so will test that first. Once we're done, of course we'll post our results. Hopefully this will help the next person. Thanks everyone!